# How to get the name of the respective mutation or query which calls the resolver

Tags: graphql

I have two mutation which maps to same resolver class. I need to differentiate between both mutations. So in-order to do that, I am looking for a functionality to fetch the name of the mutation or query in the resolver. Any ideas?

Comment: You can pass 1 additional parameters in each mutation like mutation-name=a or b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below code

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;

```
$field->getName();
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It solved my problem.